# Remove repeated values in a column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have the following HTML table:

```
Date          Desc
2018-10-01    Description 1
2018-10-01    Description 2
2018-10-01    Description 3
2018-10-01    Description 4
2018-10-02    Description 1
2018-10-02    Description 2
2018-10-02    Description 3
```

What I want is to have something like this:

```
Date          Desc
2018-10-01    Description 1
              Description 2
              Description 3
              Description 4
2018-10-02    Description 1
              Description 2
              Description 3
```

What I've tried is this:

```
var seen = {};

$('#TableId tbody tr').each(function () {
    var txt = $("td:first-child", $(this)).text();

    if (seen[txt]) $(this).text("");
    else seen[txt] = true;
});
```

But with this I get the following output:

```
Date         Desc
2018-10-01   Description 1
2018-10-02   Description 1
```

**EDIT**

Here is the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rqzraZ?editors=1010)

**UPDATE**

According to Adam answer now works fine but the problem is that in my app changes the sort order of Desc column, here is an example with my real data [image: data table]

What I'm doing wrong? And how can I solve it?

Comment: would you please post the html code for the html table?

Comment: @holaymolay I add the codepen.

Comment: which plugin do You use for sorting?

Comment: @AdamŁożyński Jquery DataTables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding *fnDrawCallback* should solve Your sorting problem:

```
$('#TableId').DataTable({
  "fnDrawCallback": updateTable
});

function updateTable(){
  var x = '';
  $('#TableId tbody tr').each(function () {
    var txt = $("td:first-child", $(this)).text();
    if(txt == x) {
      $("td:first-child", $(this)).css('visibility', 'hidden');        
    }
    else {
      $("td:first-child", $(this)).css('visibility', 'visible');
      x = txt;
    }
  });
}
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XxaBby

Answer (score 1):

If you use datatables than I think You will need [THIS](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-rowspan-in-table-body-tbody/)
Otherwise this code will work.

Check Out [this](https://codepen.io/shakogele/pen/vVmMpv?editors=1010):

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Desc</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>2018-10-01</td>
          <td>Description 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2018-10-01</td>
          <td>Description 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2018-10-01</td>
          <td>Description 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2018-10-01</td>
          <td>Description 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2018-10-02</td>
          <td>Description 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2018-10-02</td>
          <td>Description 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2018-10-02</td>
          <td>Description 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2018-10-02</td>
          <td>Description 8</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS Code:

```
var dates = {};
var i = 1;
$('.table tbody tr td:nth-child(1)').each(function(){
  var innerText = $(this).text();
  $(this).text('');
  dates[innerText] = i;
  i++;
})

var j = 1;
for (var prop in dates) {
  selector = $('.table tbody tr:nth-child('+j+') td:nth-child(1)');
  selector.attr('rowspan',dates.prop);
  selector.text(prop);
  j = dates[prop];
}
```

Comment: Your code wont work properly on second column sorting:
https://i.imgur.com/C0Z1lFV.png

Comment: In Your codepen columns sorting does not work, check OPs UPDATE statement

Comment: I just saw that you are using datatables, in That case the sorting wont work. also it would be better if you add 'datatables' tag to your question

Comment: I just updated My answer check this link https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-rowspan-in-table-body-tbody/

Answer (score 0):

You're clearing the `tr`, which removes all of the cells in the row. Instead, only clear the `td` of the column you want.

```
var seen = {};

$('#TableId tbody tr').each(function () {
    var $cell = $("td:first-child", $(this)); 
    if (seen[$cell.text()]) $cell.text("");
    else seen[$cell.text()] = true;
});
```

Comment: Your code wont work on jquery-datatables with enabled columns-sorting. Check out authors **update** statement

Comment: The OP should've commented that on your answer. I'm addressing the original question.